# merge two matrix (dataframe) into one in between columns

Tags: dataframe, merge, append, concatenation

I have two dataframe like these:

```
    df1      a  b   c
        0    1  2   3
        1    2  3   4
        2    3  4   5
```

```
    df2      x  y   z
        0    T  T   F
        1    F  T   T
        2    F  T   F
```

I want to merge these matrix according column one i between like this:

```
    df       a  x  b  y  c  z
        0    1  T  2  T  3  F
        1    2  F  3  T  4  T
        2    3  F  4  T  5  F
```

whats your idea? how we can merge or append or concate?!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df = df[['a','x','b','y','c','z']]
```

Prints:

```
   a  x  b  y  c  z
0  1  T  2  T  3  F
1  2  F  3  T  4  T
2  3  F  4  T  5  F
```

Comment: Tnx Dude. 1: your code didn't work correctly. did you check it? and if we want to change 40 columns what is answer? we should insert 40 columns name manually ?!!!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting.. can u pls paste it here...

Comment: Is order of columns important for you? If not just, plain concat will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code. it work dynamically:

```js
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,6):
    if i%2 == 0:
        j=(i)/2
        df.loc[:,i] = df1.iloc[:,int(j)]
    else:
        j=(i-1)/2
        df.loc[:,i] = df2.iloc[:,int(j)]
```

And it works correctly !!